# Converting Mouse Coords to World Coords

Tags: c++, opengl, window, coordinates, mouse

I'm trying to make a light source follow the mouse in OpenGL (C++). In world coords, the center of my screen is `(4, 1.5f)` and I get my mouse coords for the center as `(640, 360)` (window res is 1280, 720). I managed to convert the coordinates for only the center, but I can't figure out how to get the rest to convert.

For converting the center coordinate:

`shader.SetUniform("lightPos", fs::Vector2f((float) x * 8 / 1280, (float) (y * 4.5f / 720) - 0.75f));`

Another conversion I tried was `(x * 16.0f / 1280.0f), (9.0f - y * 9.0f / 720.0f)`

where x and y are the mouse coordinates.

All the solutions I've found online have not been working thus far.

In case it matters, this is my projection matrix:

`fs::Matrix4f ortho = fs::Matrix4f::Orthographic(0, 16, 0, 9, -1, 1);`

Parameters: `float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far`

For clarification, here are some images where the yellow rectangle is my mouse, which is where i want the light to render

[image: Center coordinate being correct]

[image: Now its not correct]

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you set up your view matrix so that your world coord center is `(4, 1.5)`? From the projection matrix alone, it should be at `(8, 4.5)` (assuming `Matrix4f::Orthographic` works like the standard Ortho functions).

Comment: @derhass I had found a few different calculations, but I found this one the most: http://snip.redthirddivision.com/snip/view/?id=28b43ddc6a0cf37594d14e910738debc (added it to a paste cuz comment kept messing up format) , also should note this is for a 2D game engine im working on

Comment: @derhass Also PS again, if it also helps my light pos is being calculated in shaders with `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position` where the viewMatrix currently is just filled with 1s and the modelMatrix is a translation matrix with `x = 4, y = 3, z = 0` and the projection is my ortho

Comment: Well, then you confuse the terms. You seem to want object space, not world space, if you want to take the model matrix into account for this. The world space position of some window space point is solely defined by the projection and view matrices.

Comment: @derhass how would I go about that? I can only find things about world space when google searching

Comment: Well, this isn't that relevant. We just need to know what exactly you are talking about. The generic answer to your question is _unprojecting_, just inverting the transformations which are normally done from object space to window space. Since you use an ortho projection, you can take some shortcuts, but in the end, there is not much to save.

Comment: @derhass I just added some pictures to the question to help clarify what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Just closing this, my problem was that after I did `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position;` I had forgotten in my next line to send updated position data to my fragment shader, so I had to change my line `pos = position;` (pos being an out vec4 and position being an in vec4) to `pos = modelMatrix * position;`